# Ice-cream-on-a-stick in refrigerator temperature

Tags: ice-cream

In the summer, I used to make ice-cream-on-a-stick in various flavors. Some examples:

- Chocolate flavor: melted cocoa + honey + coconut oil + almond butter.
- Banana flavor: bananas + peanut butter + cinnamon + soy milk.

I just mixed them, put in a mould, put a wooden stick in each hole, and put in the freezer. Then, I could grab one in the morning and eat on the way to work as a breakfast.

Now, winter is coming and it is unpleasant to eat at freezer temperature, so I wonder if I can achieve the same effect in refrigerator temperature: is there an ingredient I can add to the mixture, that will make it freeze, and stick to the stick, in the refrigerator?

Comment: "Freeze" obviously doesn't work in the refrigerator.  You might discard the stick idea, and do something in a cup...like a panna cotta, or other gelatin based product.  A very firm gel might adhere to a stick, but I doubt it would be pleasant to eat.

Comment: @moscafj - [Freezing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freezing) in physics/chemistry terminology just means turning a liquid into a solid through decreasing temperature. Some liquids freeze at freezer temperatures; others freeze at much higher temperatures. OP seems just to be looking for ingredients that would create a phase transition to solid ("freezing") at refrigerator temperatures.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at making a cheesecake on a stick.

It is stable at fridge and room temperature;